# Sample dependency in Neural Net Training cross-validation

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation, monte-carlo

I've created a Monte Carlo simulation that randomly divides my data into "test" and "training"-Samples and then trains a neural network. The ratio of 0 and 1 (19.62%) Category is stabilized on sampling.
My results show a highly fluctuating model accuracy (*min*=0.6452, *M*=0.7792, *max*=0.8925).
What could be possible reasons for this effect and how should I choose a test/train/model for my discussion?

Comment: Model accuracy is the wrong way to frame model quality questions; as you've discovered, it tends to be unstable. This is because it discards information. Instead, look to proper scoring rules like log-likelihood, Brier score, or ROC AUC.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I computed die AUC over the simulation     ROC-AUC: Min.: 0.4107, Mean: 0.6226, Max.: 0.9655. But now I´m even more puzzled from worse than random models to exceptionally good model fit...

Comment: and with that proper scoring rule + out-of-bootstrap or repeated/iterated cross validation look whether the variation does come from unstable predictions (model instability).

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas when facing such a situation:

- it might happen if you have a very low number of labeled samples
- try training the same neural network several times on the same train/test split, to make sure that the variability of the performance you observed isn't due to the random initialization of the weight, or random creation of the mini-batches.
- the discussion should mention that the results are heavily impacted by the train/test split
- try spotting which samples result in a significant performance difference when included in the training set

Comment: If I try the same neural network on the same train/test split and there is indeed a significant variability. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @KrombopulosMichael Do X runs and take the Y best ones according to valid set.